# Slim Framework: Setting encoding on response

Tags: php, slim

I'm having trouble setting the encoding on the response.
Tried:

- $app->contentType('text/html; charset=utf-8');
- header("Content-Type: application/json");
- $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');

I'm stuck... :-/

**EDIT**
I've downloaded the `Slim/slim-skeleton` via Composer.

I need to return JSON in my `Route.php`:

```
$app->get('/getStoresByBounds', function () use ($app, $stores) {
    $app->contentType('application/json');

    $myStores = $stores->getStores();

    $app->response()->write(json_encode($myStores));

    $app->stop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :)

```
// APP
$app = Slim::getInstance();

// CONTENT-TYPE
$app->contentType('application/json');

// STATUS
$app->status(200);

// RESPONSE ARRAY
$response = array();

// PRINT THE RESPONSE ARRAY
$app->response()->write(json_encode($response));
$app->stop();
```

Or try to access `$app` inside your function by:

```
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
```

Since you are using V3, you might use this:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->get('/getStoresByBounds', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    $myStores = $stores->getStores();

    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($myStores));

    $newResponse = $response->withHeader(
        'Content-type',
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    );

    return $newResponse;
});
```

Comment: I can't use it in the route - it says "undefined class". Tried to `use ($app)` in the route, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you add use Slim\Slim; at the top of your class? Or can you show some example code?

Comment: When I try your ladder example, it still says that Slim is an undefined class. I use the latest version of Slim, version 3.2.1. In version 2.6.1 (my last project) there wasn't an issue... :-(

Comment: Shouldn't I use version 3? It still has issues. `Request` is an undefined class... :-( I think I'm returning to version 2... :)

Comment: @KennethB Try to access request and response by calling \Slim\Request or something :)

Comment: Are you by chance trying to run Slim 2 code with Slim 3? I'm pretty sure both versions are not compatible at all.

Comment: @KennethB If you are finding bugs in Slim 3, please report them as an issue here: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues

Answer (score 1):

From [The Response/ Headers/ Set Header](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#set-header):

```
$newResponse = $oldResponse->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Saw that in the documentation. But what is `$oldResponse`? I just need to send the response in the Route.

Comment: Please check the [Get Started](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/) section for that. The response is the second argument of the route handler. And now I think about your code... Are you using Slim 3? I assumed that because you never mentioned using an old version but your code attempts don't seem to match current versions.

Comment: To @downvoter... Care to explain why a pointer to the specific documentation section that explains the subject is "not useful"?

Comment: I'm using version 3, but I now see that the docs are only version 2... :-O Now I get why I'm so comfussed :-D

Comment: You see that were? Did you follow my link?